oauth2_provider in Django is not validating the token correctly
I have a django rest api and trying to authenticate the endpoints using oauth2_provider. I guess I have added the settings for above library correctly to my settings file.
urls.py
from django.urls import re_path

from slatemath.apps.mrl.views import TokenVerificationView, MRLClassDetailsView

urlpatterns = [
    re_path(r"verify-token/$", TokenVerificationView.as_view(), name="verify-token"),
    re_path(r"school_id/(?P<id>[-\w]+)/classes/$", MRLClassDetailsView.as_view(), name="fetch-class-details"),
]

Below is the view,
from oauth2_provider.views.mixins import OAuthLibMixin, ScopedResourceMixin

class TokenVerificationView(ScopedResourceMixin, OAuthLibMixin, View):
    required_scopes = ['read', 'write']
        def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        print(request.META)
        if hasattr(request, 'client'):
            client = request.client
            ...

class MRLClassDetailsView(ScopedResourceMixin, OAuthLibMixin, View):
    required_scopes = ['read']

    def get(self, request, id, *args, **kwargs):
        print(request.META)
        ...

As per above codes, the issue is, when I pass the bearer token in the header, the "verify-token" endpoint is working without any issue, but the fetch-class-details call is not validating the token correctly, It's allowing with an invalid token, even an empty token in the header.
What am I missing here?
